# empty space in ASP.NET page containing two columnar DIVs

Tags: asp.net, html

I use VS2010 for ASP.NET development, I should insert two columnar DIVs next to each other (width same height):

```
<div style="height:605px; width: 610px; top:10px; position:relative; right:-125px; border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;  background-color: #F3F3F3;" align="left">
</div>

                <div style="height:605px; width: 233px; border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;  top:-600px; right:314px; background-color: #EDEDED; position: relative;" 
                    align="left">
</div>
```

it works fine but I have some dead zone at bottom of my page!!, this dead zone (empty space) is the same height as my divs (605px)!!! what is going wrong here? how can I remove this empty space at bottom of my page? you can see this problem in this address:
http://www.data-kitchens.com/News.aspx

thanks

Comment: I could solve my problem! of course I'd be happy to know about other solutions, this is what I did: I created a big DIV containing both of these two DIVs, then I removed right and top tags from style of these two, I just used float: left and float: right, then it worked as expected! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the height from style and let it consume as much space it should have. I just checked using firebug. It started to work fine. You can do this in your fourth div

### Replace your following div

```
<div align="left" style="height:605px; width:  610px; overflow:auto; top:-595px; right:-125px; border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;  background-color: #F3F3F3; position: relative;">
```

### with following div

```
<div align="left" style="width:  610px; overflow:auto; top:-595px; right:-125px; border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;  background-color: #F3F3F3; position: relative;">
```